# Can we use non-Invertibility property of a matrix to detect linearly dependent features?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, feature-selection, feature-engineering

In order to find whether two features (such as the size of a house in feet^2 and metert^2 ) are linearly dependent or not? One way of finding it is!

you take the transpose of the feature vector and multiply by itself if you get a non-invertible matrix, there you go, you find these 2 features are linear dependent, so throw one off!

This intuition I get from the normal equation method to compute the model parameters of a linear model!

[image]

Wherein the cause of (X_T*X) to be non-invertible is :
1. there are 2 linearly correlated features!
2. the number of training examples(say 10) are very few compare to the number of features(say 100)

- Is a mathematically proven fact that? if it is then it's okay to use this method to find linearly correlated features and throw one of them?
- What are other methods for finding correlated features, if they are related something other than linear?
- What are other methods to detect two or more linearly correlated features?

Comment: Your method works only for two features.  With more than two, the non-invertibility of $X^\prime X$ only tells you there is collinearity--and removing one variable might not resolve it.  A general set of methods to diagnose and detect collinearity (and, more importantly, near-collinearity, often termed "multicollinearity") was published by Belsley, Kuh, and Welsch in *Regression Diagnostics* (1980).

Comment: @whuber, great! do you know where I can see an implementation of those in ML libraries such as sklearn, tensorflow or any other? Also, Could you point to me to some working demonstration(code) that uses such a method?

Comment: `R` supports some of the methods (and enables one to program them all).  I have run across some standard output from SAS that contains some of the more esoteric collinearity diagnostics, but am not familiar enough with it to give you a specific reference.

Comment: @whuber, could you point me to those methods in R specifically?

Comment: A place to begin, even though it's only indirectly related, is with the suite of regression diagnostic functions: see `?influence.measures`.  I haven't seen the full multicollinearity diagnostics implemented.  As described in section 3.2 of Belsley *et al.*, these are based on the SVD of the model matrix.  That is available through the `svd` and `La.svd` functions in base `R`.